# How to implement a Kafka event handler in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I need to Implement kafka event handler using python. I know basic about producer and consumer and topics. What are the functionalities should I handle to implement event handler?.

What are the things should I focus on to create an event handler?

Answer (score 1):

If you understand consumers, then the rest is basic Python; define a function that handles the records

For example,

```
def handle(record):
   pass  # TODO

def main():
    c = KafkaConsumer('some-topic', ...)
    for msg in c:
        handle(msg)
```

https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/